# How to setup google workbox with vue JS spa

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have an Ionic project built on VUE Js, and I am trying to configure the @vue/cli-plugin-pwa which is essentially an abstraction of google workbox.

I have created a `vue.config.js` file with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
     swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
    }
  }
}
```

and the `src/service-worker.js` contents are

```
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

I am trying to handle "fallback responses" for when the user is offline(No internet) as mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/managing-fallback-responses/) in the official docs to avoid the default "no internet" page. Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to implement it.

I have spent days trying to figure this out and have gone over the docs several times, I understand what the docs are implying but I just can't figure out how/where to implement this in VUE js. And the official Vue CLI docs on the subject ([link here](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html)) are pretty much moot.

Would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out or show me some sample repos.

Answer (score 2):

After taking a few days off and looking back at it now, I have realized that the currents docs by google are for workbox version 6, and documentation for workbox version 5 is marked legacy.

Whereas the `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` plugin has a dependency for workbox version 4.3, which is severely outdated; there are a lot of breaking changes and compatibility issues between the two. Given this fact and that I am short on time I started to look in a different direction.

After some trial and error, I have reverted back to the `GenerateSW` method as it exposes a `navigateFallback` option, which if set to the entry file, in my case `index.html` prevents the default "no internet" page in case of a refresh by the user when offline.

Additionally, I have resorted to handling the API errors in the application by intercepting the Axios calls.

If anyone is interested this is my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
        workboxOptions: {
            navigateFallback: '/index.html',
            cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
            importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
            importScripts: ['/inject-sw.js']
        }
    }
}
```

I know this might not be the proper way of doing it, but this at least solves the problem for now.

If anyone has a better way of doing it, feel free to point it out.

Also, this "[article](https://medium.com/@dougallrich/give-users-control-over-app-updates-in-vue-cli-3-pwas-20453aedc1f2)" was very resourceful when I was trying to understand how it all works.